# Legal abbreviation: "Hal. pl. cr."

Tags: criminal-law, england-and-wales

What does the abbreviation "Hal. pl. cr." in legal reporting refer to?

Comment: Adding context - where these abbreviations were found, for instance, and what they look like _in situ_ - would be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

I've retracted and replaced my previous answer.

It is a citation to legal authority.

It is probably a reference to the book "[Hale, The History of the Pleas of the Crown](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/15/Matthew_Hale%2C_Historia_Placitorum_Coron%C3%A6_%281st_American_ed%2C_1847%2C_vol_1%29.pdf) Hale PC" (originally published 1736 with later editions also printed) (see [4.2.3](https://www.law.ox.ac.uk/sites/files/oxlaw/oscola_4th_edn_hart_2012.pdf)) with Hale abbreviated "Hal.", "pl." being an abbreviation for "plea" (see 4.2.2) and "cr." being an abbreviation for "crown". [Standard citation form](https://www.worldcat.org/title/historia-placitorum-coron-the-history-of-the-pleas-of-the-crown-by-sir-matthew-hale-now-first-published-from-his-lordships-original-manuscript-and-the-several-references-to-the-records-examined-by-the-originals-with-large-notes-by-sollom-emlyn-to-which-is-added-a-table-of-the-principal-matters-in-two-volumes/oclc/64151524?page=citation) is to spell it out, but if it is cited repeatedly later instances might be abbreviated.

The link is to a scanned version of the out of copyright historical legal treatise on criminal procedure and substantive criminal law. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Historia_Placitorum_Coron%C3%A6) also discusses it as does a l[aw library Wiki](https://lawlibrary.wm.edu/wythepedia/index.php/History_of_the_Pleas_of_the_Crown).